# getting long hexadecimal hash

Tags: python, r, encryption, hash, cryptography

How can I convert this python code to R?

```py
import hashlib

def str_buckets(a, b, buckets):
  return (int(hashlib.md5(str(a + ',' + b).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), 16) & 4294967295) % buckets
```

I am able to write

```py
hashlib.md5(b'x,y').hexdigest()
```

to

```r
digest::digest("x,y", algo="md5", serialize=FALSE)
```

both of them giving me output of `f10bc3c94b77e1d6b9f98106daf335c1`

BUT in python

```py
int(hashlib.md5(b'x,y').hexdigest(), 16)
```

is outputting `320405033267698290319193645506345776577`

is there an R equivalent to `python`'s `int(<>, 16)`?

Comment: Converting to integers in `R` can be done by using `as.integer`. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: its not just integer, it will be integer with base 16, and that is what python code does. Not able to find any function to convert in the specified `320405033267698290319193645506345776577` in `R`

Comment: Can you try `Rmpfr` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/Rmpfr.pdf and use `mpfr` function with base 16

Comment: perhaps directly use python code via `reticulate` package? Try  something like `py_run_string("num = int('516',16)")`

Comment: `reticulate` is what i am currently doing with the whole python definition using `source_python`, but I am creating an API using `plumber` and calling python definition inside R, is making it slower

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, R doesn't have native capability to handle big integers (only 32-bit).  This will give the right answer:

```
d <- digest::digest("x,y", algo="md5", serialize=FALSE)
library(Rmpfr)
m <- mpfr(d,precBits=200,base=16)
## 1 'mpfr' number of precision  200   bits 
## [1] 320405033267698290319193645506345776577
```

but working with this further in R might be challenging.  I wasn't even finding a way to get a string equivalent of it that was cleaner than:

```
gsub("\\.0+$","",format(m))
## [1] "320405033267698290319193645506345776577"
```

Installing the `Rmpfr` package will require installing [MPFR](http://mpfr.org/) and [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score -1):

Isn't `as.hexmode()` what you need?

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/hexmode.html

Comment: this will be hard because the original value is too large for R's integer type (R doesn't have arbitrary-sized integers unless you go to `Rmpfr`.